# Lie algebra of 2D Poincare group

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given the Poincare group in 2D:

$
P=\{\begin{pmatrix}e^{x}&0&y\\0&e^{-x}&z\\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}: x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}\}
$

how do I determine its corresponding Lie algebra $p$?

I know that any matrix Lie group element can be generated as $e^X$, where $X$ is an element of its Lie algebra. I suppose one would start expanding $e^X=\mathbb{1}+X$ close to the identity and hence for $X\in P$ we have$\begin{pmatrix}x&0&y\\0&-x&z\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}
$.